# Qt - How to set up shortcut contexts for actions in in menu and widgets

Tags: qt, shortcut

I have some global menu actions which are attached to the main menuBar ("Zoom" in the example below). Additionally, I have actions attached to certain widgets ("Zoom2" in the example below).

I would like to use the same shortcut for both actions. It should work like this:

- if `textEdit2` is focussed, its action should consume the shortcut (i.e. `zoom2()` should be triggered).
- otherwise, the menu shortcut should get active, triggering `zoomGlobal()`.

The current example below does not work yet: If `textEdit2` is focussed, Qt notifies `QAction::eventFilter: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Ctrl++` and does nothing.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QAction *act = menuBar()->addAction("Zoom");
    act->setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl++"));
    connect(act, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(zoomGlobal()));

    setCentralWidget(new QWidget());
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    centralWidget()->setLayout(layout);
    QTextEdit *textEdit1 = new QTextEdit();
    layout->addWidget(textEdit1);

    QTextEdit *textEdit2 = new QTextEdit();
    layout->addWidget(textEdit2);
    act = new QAction("Zoom2");
    act->setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl++"));
    act->setShortcutContext(Qt::WidgetShortcut);
    connect(act, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(zoom2()));
    textEdit2->addAction(act);
}
```

**Is there a way for a focussed widget to steal and consume a shortcut, no matter if there is another shorcut with context `WindowShortcut` or `ApplicationShortcut`**?

Of course, it would be possible to code all the stuff in `zoomGlobal()`, check which widget is active and delegate to its action. However, that's quite cumbersome if you have many actions and widgets. I would like to be able add/remove/change widgets like `textEdit2` without the need to adapt code in `zoomGlobal()`.

Comment: After more than two hours of search and attemps I have absolutely no idea how it can be done without the global check)). You have to check whether the `textEdit2` is active or not active during the global shortcut event. This is not bad, because your program of course will not have many such pairs, and the check is simple )

Comment: @VladimirBershov: Thanks for your work. Actually, the above is only a minimal example. The actual program has several widgets like `textEdit2` and each with multiple (and different) shortcuts. The global check is nothing I can seriously introduce. If anything, one would have to write a framework around that. All widgets and actions would have to be registered there and the framework would have to delegate. But I hope that there is another way.

Comment: Please note that this is a strange example. I don't know anything about your main project, but this peace of code looks bad - non-informative variable names which differ only by numbers, creating UI elements in the code, strange line `setCentralWidget(new QWidget());` . Global check is not a problem, it can be just encapsulated in a class, like everything else.

Comment: This is really just a minimal example for testing (you can create a project and paste the above code for a working example). You may think of it as a code editor `textEdit1` and other related widgets `textEdit2`. "creating UI elements in the code": IMHO nothing wrong with that. "strange line setCentralWidget(new QWidget());": This is just a container on which I can set the layout. "Global [...] can be just encapsulated in a class": that's what I meant by framework.

Comment: I feel your pain, I have exactly this problem too. Having to do the global ckecks is of course possible, but as in your case that would need a quite large framework around it in a real application with lots of widgets/shortcut. Can't understad that there's so little written about this!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you. To solve it, you use a trick inside the QShortcut class.

In your example code, you want 'textEdit2' to steal a global shortcut when it has focus. This code should do it, it works for me:

```
QTextEdit* textEdit2 = new QTextEdit();
layout->addWidget(textEdit2);
QShortcut* shortcutStealer = new QShortcut(
    QKeySequence("Ctrl++"),  //the key sequence to steal
    textEdit2,               //the shortcut's parent
    SLOT(zoom2()),           //triggered when shortcut activated
    SLOT(zoom2()),           //triggered when shortcut ambiguously activated! 
    Qt::WidgetShortcut);     //context of shortcut
```

Hope this is clear and helps you. Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer still has value for anyone who comes across this shortcut context problem, and can save you couple hours of struggling with Qt QShortcut.

Long story in short: Qt think shortcuts with same key sequence(e.g. CTRL+F) defined on both parent and child widgets is the case of `ambiguity`, and signals `activatedAmbiguously()` will be emitted in one by one in bubble order(the order of top to bottom, first `QMainWindow` then `QTextEdit` then `QMainWindow`... to infinite loop).

> From Qt offical document: When the user types the key sequence for a given shortcut, the shortcut’s activated() signal is emitted. (In the case of ambiguity, the activatedAmbiguously() signal is emitted.) A shortcut is “listened for” by Qt’s event loop when the shortcut’s parent widget is receiving events.

As a result, if you have `QShortcut` objects with same `QKeySeqence` `CTRL+F` on `QMainWindow` and `QTextEdit`(center widget of `QMainWindow`), no matter you focus(mouse click in) on `QTextEdit` or `QMainWindow`. When you press `CTRL+F`. None of shortcut will emit signal `activated`, but signal `activatedAmbiguously` will be emitted in the order of `['QMainWindow.QShortcut.activatedAmbiguously', 'QTextEdit.QShortcut.activatedAmbiguously', 'QMainWindow.QShortcut.activatedAmbiguously' ...]`.

This behavior is checked by me after several exhausting hours of testing QShortcut in different senario again and again. You can refer to the unittest(requires pytest, pytest-qt and PySide6) code I post below:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
import pytest

def test_shortcut_override(qtbot):
    """
    In this test we have built a simple UI has an QTextEdit in an QMainWindow,
    Both QTextEdit and QMainWindow has same shortcut 'Ctrl+F'. The shortcuts
    emit `activatedAmbiguously()` signal in bubble order.
    """
    from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
    import random

    mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    qtbot.add_widget(mainWindow)

    # build UI hierarchy
    textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(textEdit)

    # window must be shown, otherwise the shortcut will never work since it
    # needs window to receive the shortcut event
    mainWindow.show()

    mainWindowSCAmbigouslyTrigger = MagicMock(returns=None)
    textEditSCAmbigouslyTrigger = MagicMock(returns=None)

    mainWindowMockSC = MagicMock(returns=None)
    textEditMockSC = MagicMock(returns=None)

    sc = QtGui.QShortcut('Ctrl+F', mainWindow, mainWindowMockSC, QtGui.Qt.ShortcutContext.ApplicationShortcut)
    sc.activatedAmbiguously.connect(mainWindowSCAmbigouslyTrigger)

    sc = QtGui.QShortcut('Ctrl+F', textEdit, textEditMockSC, QtGui.Qt.ShortcutContext.WidgetWithChildrenShortcut)
    sc.activatedAmbiguously.connect(textEditSCAmbigouslyTrigger)

    mainWindowSCAmbiguouslyCount = 0
    textEditSCAmbiguouslyCount = 0

    for i in range(20):
        # no matter which widget is focus, it doesn't change the bubble order.
        widget = random.choice([textEdit, mainWindow])
        widget.setFocus()
        qtbot.keyClicks(widget, 'F', QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifier.ControlModifier, delay=1)

        # Result 1) neither shortcut's signal `activated` not emitted, so these two not called.
        mainWindowMockSC.assert_not_called()
        textEditMockSC.assert_not_called()

        # Result 2) shortcuts are ambiguously activated in bubble order.
        if i % 2 == 0:
            mainWindowSCAmbiguouslyCount += 1
        else:
            textEditSCAmbiguouslyCount += 1

        assert mainWindowSCAmbigouslyTrigger.call_count == mainWindowSCAmbiguouslyCount
        assert textEditSCAmbigouslyTrigger.call_count == textEditSCAmbiguouslyCount

        print(f"'CTRL+F' has been triggered: {i + 1} times.")
        print(f"QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: {mainWindowSCAmbigouslyTrigger.call_count} times.")
        print(f"QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: {textEditSCAmbigouslyTrigger.call_count} times.")
```

Output:

```
PASSED                 [100%]
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 1 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 1 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 0 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 2 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 1 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 1 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 3 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 2 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 1 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 4 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 2 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 2 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 5 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 3 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 2 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 6 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 3 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 3 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 7 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 4 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 3 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 8 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 4 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 4 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 9 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 5 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 4 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 10 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 5 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 5 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 11 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 6 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 5 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 12 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 6 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 6 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 13 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 7 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 6 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 14 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 7 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 7 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 15 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 8 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 7 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 16 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 8 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 8 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 17 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 9 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 8 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 18 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 9 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 9 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 19 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 10 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 9 times.
'CTRL+F' has been triggered: 20 times.
QMainWindow's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 10 times.
QTextEdit's shortcut ambiguously triggered: 10 times.
```

I'm sure this "ambiguous" shortcut behavior is same in Qt/C++.

> "Is there a way for a focussed widget to steal and consume a shortcut, no matter if there is another shortcut with context WindowShortcut or ApplicationShortcut?"

Saddly, the answer is NO, but since you know that shortcuts with same key sequence will emit `activatedAmbiguously` signal in bubble order. You can exploit this behavior by binding all `activatedAmbiguously` signal to one SLOT function, and in that function you can use `QApplication::focusWidget()` to get focused widget then trigger the shortcut action by yourself now.

I won't post the implementation here because since you've read this far, you should fully understand `QShortcut` ambiguity and how signals are emitted in bubble order now, go and try it yourself :)